# Returning a list of values from a list of dictionaries where keys equal a certain value

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
<div id="tabs" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="remove">
        <li class="btn_arrow_tab left inactive">
            <a href="#" class="doubleText">Pay Monthly <small>View standard rates and Bolt Ons</small>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="btn_arrow_tab right inactive">
            <a href="#" class="doubleText">Pay &amp; Go<small>View standard rates and Bolt Ons</small>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have no experience in webscraping and trying to follow example and the docs to click on the button with text 'Pay Monthly'. This button then dynamically displays some text which I need to copy. How do I go about clicking this for starters, and then reading the text which is displayed. I am trying it with Selenium, would beautifulsoup be better? I have been trying this line of code but it isn't doing anything:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()[contains(.,'Pay Monthly')]]").click()
```

Comment: Beautifulsoup is definitely not suited for this kind of task. It only parses html and can be used to extract information from it, but it has little to do with actually interacting with real web pages.

Comment: What you mean `doing anything`? Do you get an exception or it's just not clicking the button? Text should appears in the same button instead of `"Pay Monthly"`?

Answer (score 0):

It is always good practice to use mixture of absolute and relative xpath to locate a element.

First thing you should find is a parent that has a unique identifier. The element you mentioned has two parent items with a static id. One is root `div` and another is `ul`.

Now either we can follow your path and find the element using Text. Any of the following shall work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='tabs']//a[text()[contains(.,'Pay Monthly')]]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='remove']//a[text()[contains(.,'Pay Monthly')]]").click()
```

But, if the item is static element and considering your goal here, I would suggest the following method. indexing your xpath when it returns multiple elements.

```
myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='tabs']//a[@href='#'][1]")
myElement.click()
```

And then you can capture the text. You can put some `wait` to ensure the text gets changed.

```
myText = myElement.text
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.